# Oozie Resolving Jar versions

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, amazon-emr

I have an oozie job running with yarn scheduler.

Two actions in my oozie job are a spark job followed by a java job.

I have jackson version 2.6 in my spark assmbly jar and jackson 2.9 in my java assembly jar. Now my spark fails with exception

```
>     java.lang.Exception: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.3
>       at com.sps.analytics.batch.bi.BatchApp.executeQueries(BatchApp.scala:73)
>       at com.sps.analytics.batch.bi.BatchApp$.main(BatchApp.scala:32)
```

How Do I force my spark application jar to use 2.6 version

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5" force()

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.6.5" force()

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.5" force()

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-yaml" % "2.6.5" force()
```

this is what i have in my spark build.sbt

Comment: Your Oozie Spark job and Java job should be independent. May be the Jackson library 2.9 is loaded by YARN (check the YARN logs) causing this conflict. If the case, try to use the parameter `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first` (https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6610/can-i-ensure-that-my-own-jars-have-classpath-prior.html)

Comment: does not seem to work :(

Comment: Oozie job works fine as separate jobs, but when i create one job with the two tasks it doesn't seem to be working. I m getting conflicts where my spark app is complaining it  has higher version of jackson, which is use in the other jar. Between both of my jars are assembly jars.

Comment: How to exclude jars in lib from an action in a workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the Java action a sub-workflow helps resolve the issues